# "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" in 2D, Text-Based, Map Generator

Tags: python, macos, pygame

Alright. In the code below I am trying to take a (multi-line) .txt file, stored in my_heightmap, and turn it into a list, which I then reformat as an array (such that heightarray is separately holding every value in each row of what will become a two-dimensional, text-based heightmap.) I'm getting the "not subscriptable" error on this line:

```
heightarray[y[x]] = heightlist[count + x]
```

I'm not sure where I messed up, but as I understand it, the code should take each line of the .txt file and convert it into its own list within heightarray. I'm not sure why I can't take a single instance of a list of values and turn it into a single instance of an array (which is just a list within a list)?

This is possibly woefully inefficient, but I'm just trying to earn my chops on a project that interests me.

```
 #converting the heightmap into an array
    heightlist = list(my_heightmap)
    heightarray = []
    count = 0

    for y in range(0,self.size):
        for x in range(0, self.size):
            heightarray[y[x]] = heightlist[count + x]
        count += self.size

    #peak generation
    for peaks in range(0, round(self.size/30)):
        y = random.randomint(0,size + 1)
        x = random.randomint(0,size + 1)
        for dist in range(0, random.randomint(size/50, size/10)):
            heightarray[y[x]] = 9
            y += random.randomint(-1,2)
            x += random.randomint(-1,2)

    my_heightmap.write(heightarray)
    my_heightmap.close()
```

My apologies if this is a fairly simple fix (I didn't really find another similar question that made sense to me) and I'm probably not using the correct jargon. Thank you for any and all help!

P.S. I hope I've explained the situation enough. I am happy to post more code or explain further if needed!

Comment: `for y in range(0, self.size)` makes `y` an integer, which you try to treat like a list with `y[x]`. Not sure, what you intended to do in this step. Maybe `heightarray[y][x]`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the `y[x]` since y is an int. You probably want to initialize heightarray as a 2D list and do `heightarray[y][x] = ...`. See here for more details: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~112/notes/notes-2d-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

In this code, `y` is clearly an integer:

```
for y in range(0,self.size):
    for x in range(0, self.size):
        heightarray[y[x]] = heightlist[count + x]
```

What do you expect `y[x]` to do?  As the error message says, you can't subscript into an integer value.